# Estimating $\int_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function, and take $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$. For $R>\max\{|a|,|b|\},$
estimate 
$$\int_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz.$$
Assuming $f$ is bounded, let $R\rightarrow\infty$ and show $f$ is constant.

I'm not sure what it means by "estimate", are we supposed to take an upper and lower bound?

Also, after reading the second part, I suspect that it's actually a derivation of Liouville's Theorem, as the only condition to apply the theorem is that $f$ is an entire bounded function...

Comment: Are you assume $f$ is bounded and entire or boundedness is a result of integration?

Comment: I think $f$ is entire *and* bounded in the second part. The question was given as is.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, due to residue theorem this should be equal to $2\pi i (f(a) + f(b))$ no?

Comment: $2\pi i\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ I think!

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that if $|f| \le B$, your integrand is bounded by $\dfrac{B}{(R-|a|)(R-|b|)}$ so the integral is bounded by $\dfrac{2\pi R B}{(R-|a|)(R-|b|)}$.  What happens to this as $R \to \infty$?  Compare to the result of the residue theorem.